# Query to find missing weeks in timesheet

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, gaps-and-islands

I am new to flask and ORM, and I am writing a sample application for my learning.

I have this model:

```
class Timesheet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Timesheet'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable='False')
    start_date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    end_date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    total_time = Column(String(), nullable=False)
```

Every user needs to submit his timesheets for every week and we need to report timesheets if he missed any.

For example **user1** timesheets are like this

```
Start_date | end_date
---------------------
2013-07-01 | 2013-07-08 
2013-07-08 | 2013-07-15
2013-07-22 | 2013-07-29
```

We need to report missed (`2013-07-15 | 2013-07-22`) time sheet

How can I query to get this result in sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing is known by the name *gaps and islands* in SQL world. You can google it (there's plenty of information on this topic) or [download](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/) for free chapter 5 from *SQL Server MVP Deep Dives* book which is dedicated to this problem. Adapted first gaps example from this chapter to SQLAlachemy follows:

```py
t1 = aliased(Timesheet)
t2 = aliased(Timesheet)

subq1 = session.query(
    func.min(t2.start_date)
).filter(
    (t2.start_date > t1.end_date) &
    (t2.user_id == t1.user_id)
).correlate(t1).as_scalar()

subq2 = session.query(t2).filter(
    (t2.start_date == t1.end_date) &
    (t2.user_id == t1.user_id)
).correlate(t1)

subq3 = session.query(
    func.max(t2.start_date)
).filter(
    t2.user_id == t1.user_id
).correlate(t1)

print session.query(
    t1.user_id,
    t1.end_date.label('start_date'),
    subq1.label('end_date')
).filter(
    (~subq2.exists()) &
    (t1.end_date < subq3)
).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL queries can only look for data that is in the database, not for data that is missing, so to locate missing time periods efficiently you will need to restructure your database a bit.

My recommendation is that you pre-fill your table with data. It would work more or less like this:

- Before you start entering timesheets for the ending week you run a script that adds an empty time sheet for all your users for that week. The script will add timesheet entries that, for example, have the `total_time` field set to empty. (BTW, I noticed that this field is a string, shouldn't it be an integer instead?).
- Next you enter the timesheets that you receive from users. This will basically just update the empty `total_time` fields with actual values, because the records for all the timesheets were already created by the script.
- Now you can find missing timesheets with a simple query that looks for an empty `total_time` field and prints the start/end dates of those records, something that SQL can do very efficiently if there is an index on the `total_time` field.

Answer (score 1):

I would create one more table: weeks that will have records of all weeks in the possible past and future.

```
Weeks:
    id
    start_time
    end_time
```

Then I should write a query that will right join Timesheet with Weeks table and filter by Timesheet.start_dat is null. In this case you would want to have indexes on start and end dates columns.

BTW do all user have same week start and end dates for the same calendar week?
If yes - I would normalize the database and would just add Timesheet.week_id.